# How does Android uses values folders?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I have the font size defined in my dimens.xml (e.g `<dimen name="name_text_size">12sp</dimen>`)

Since this size wasn't ok on all screens I created some additional folders with different values:

- values-xhdpi
- values-xlarge-mdpi
- values-large-mdpi

I thought this should be enough, since before creating this layouts the text look ok on ldpi, mdpi and hdpi screens, but actually the font became too large. The problem is that I am not able to figure out from which file it takes the value now for these screens. Initially, I thought it uses the default value from the folder "values", but actually no layout is using that value. **Can somebody help me understand(I sow [Providing documentaion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) and [Support Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)) how this folders are working and how could I optimize the number of defined resources (e.g. xhdpi and large-mdpi have the same values)?**

The solution is simple create the following folders:

- values-ldpi
- values-mdpi
- values-hdpi

But I don't want to make things more complicated than they must be.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the different string text in each Values-folder. Once it will run you can check from which folder its taking the string values.

You can achieve this by this trick.

Comment: I already checked that it is none from the values I defined, by changing the value to 1sp (the text is no longer visible at this value for the corresponding devices), my question is from where does it take its value for hdpi, mdpi and ldpi when I don't defined them?